# Skaffold.yaml not being parsed correctly

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I have the following skaffold.yaml config file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifest:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: hamza9899/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

But when I run `skaffold dev` I get the following error :

````
  line 16: field manifest not found in type v2alpha3.KubectlDeploy```
````

Comment: @Turing85 Can you explain how Skaffold is not a developer tool? See also the Skaffold tag description.

Comment: @Jonas It is (sadly not a tool *commonly used* by developers.

Comment: @Turing85 What other people would use Skaffold? I think it is **only** used by developers. See https://skaffold.dev/ See e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTNrzEjROCo

Comment: So? I did not say that it is used by other people, only that it is not *commonly used* by developers.

Comment: Its a _developer tool_ - so it is on-topic.

Comment: I think the comments are the wrong place to discuss this topic. You are welcome to discuss this with desternaut, Braiam and me in the SOCVR chat.

Comment: @HamzaLAHLOU please read the [help/on-topic] page.

Comment: What I find weird is that I found similar question about the same tool here in stackoverflow but not closed!

Comment: I think this is a simple typo, it should be *manifests* (plural), as per https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/deployers/kubectl/

Comment: @Turing85 I'm part of the Skaffold team.  Skaffold is software development tool commonly used in building Kubernetes applications.  It is used by thousands of developers on a daily basis, it has 60k+ stars on github, and there are [more than 10,000 `skaffold.yaml`s found in Github alone](https://github.com/search?q=filename%3Askaffold.yaml&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=).  How is _commonly_ defined, and when did being a _commonly used_ tool become a requirement for SO?

Comment: @BriandeAlwis that the tool must be *commonly used* is defined on the [help/on-topic]-page.

Comment: That says _software tools commonly used by programmers_, and not _commonly used software tools_.  That’s looking at a segmentation of a tool’s user-base, not quantification of the user-base.